# Android - как system.out.println вывести в textview?

Tags: android

Добрый день! Недавно начал изучать программирование в андроиде, и решил взяться за работу с apache poi. Данные отлично выводятся, всё шикарно. Но есть одна проблема - выводятся данные через system.out.println. А надо, чтобы они были на textView. Что мне делать, как мне быть? Понимаю, что очень-очень нуб в этом, но ничего поделать не могу. Очень хочу узнать. 
Помогите, пожалуйста. 
Вот код:

```
package com.example.tests_excel;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {

           Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(getAssets().open("test.xls"));

           Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

           for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
               Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
               Cell name = row.getCell(0);
               Cell age = row.getCell(1);
               System.out.println(name.getStringCellValue() +" "+  age.getNumericCellValue());
           }
            //TextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
            //textView.setText(name.getStringCellValue() +" "+  age.getNumericCellValue());

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            return;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

В стандартном Android'е системный поток `System.out` перенаправляется на LogCat, правда, это верно не для всех устройств. Иногда это идет прямиком на `/dev/null`

В принципе можно перенаправить системный поток на другое устройство/буфер. Делается это через [setOut()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)), правда не уверен, что ось не выкинет исключение - типа `SecurityException`.

Если перенаправление получится, то надо создать собственный класс наследующий от `PrintStream` и имеющий внутренний буфер, куда и будет копиться ваш вывод из `System.out`, далее буфер можно уже выводить на `TextView`.

Но в общем и целом - это костыли.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println` принимает обычные строки, так же как и метод `setText` у `TextView`. Более того, закомментированный Вами код в методе `onCreate` как раз и делает *почти* то, что Вам нужно. Необходимо только собрать весь вывод воедино с помощью `StringBuilder` и отобразить на UI:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
       StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
       Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(getAssets().open("test.xls"));

       Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

       for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
           Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
           Cell name = row.getCell(0);
           Cell age = row.getCell(1);
           output
              .append(name.getStringCellValue())
              .append(' ')
              .append(age.getNumericCellValue())
              .append('\n');
       }
       TextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
       textView.setText(output.toString());

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return;
    }
}
```

При условии, конечно, что Ваш файл разметки `activity_main.xml` действительно содержит видимое пользователю `TextView` с `android:id="@+id/TextView1"`.